# Implement delayed jquery change event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

What I basically want to achieve is create some kind of `delayedChange` plugin to be able to call some action (such as ajax call to the server) only after some delay the last input change event was fired. At the moment I've came up with [this (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/dimetriusifua/wbzd6jec/). I should see alert only in 5 seconds (5000 msec) the last text change had place but it fires immediately.

```
(function ($) {
    var timer;
    $.fn.delayedChange = function (onchange, delay) {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).bind('change', function () {
                if (typeof onchange == 'function') {
                    window.clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = window.setTimeout(onchange.call(this), delay);
                }
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('input').delayedChange(function(){        
        alert($(this).attr('id'));        
    }, 5000);
});
```

The weirdest is that this code actually worked for some time, and then it's functionality just vanished for no reason. Obviously there is some explanation but I can't see it for now. Are there some more certain ways to implement/improve such plugin?

Comment: `alert($(this).attr('id'));` DOM natively does this, `this.id` is nicer than a jQuery object, no?

Comment: `onchange.call(this)` is run immediately, wrap it in a function and pass the jQuery reference to it.

Comment: @Joe Or `onchange.bind(this)` which returns a function. FYI  OP `on` is preferred over `bind` as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wbzd6jec/20/

Comment: @adeneo Excellent catch on the shared timer!

Comment: @RGraham - thanks, I have to admit I didn't even think about it, but generally you want to use `data` in plugins. Seems I forgot a console.log in there, was typing fast, but not fast enough to beat you.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you've described is called "debouncing". Libraries such as underscore, lodash, and ampersand have [a debounce method](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) to make this effect convenient.'

With underscore, the code is:

```
$('input').each(function () {
    $(this).on('change', _.debounce(...your function..., 5000));
});
```

No new function is needed, although you will need to include a new dependency.

---

I'd made a mistake with the first version. You need to generate a separate debounce function for each element, otherwise changing different elements will cause the timer to reset for all of the elements.

Comment: You're right :) There's very helpful, lightweight jQuery function - https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce If you want you can add it to your answer.